# Error authenticating user and displaying validation messages in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I'm facing difficulties with user authentication and displaying validation messages in Laravel. When attempting to log in, the user is not authenticated correctly, and the validation error messages are not displayed.

I followed the official Laravel documentation for authentication and validation, but I'm not getting the expected result even with the help of artificial intelligence. Here are some of my code snippets:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $request->session()->put('user', $user);
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'email' => 'Invalid email or password.',
    ]);
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
    @csrf
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, the routes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;

Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');
Route::get('/users/create', [UserController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/users', [UserController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
Route::get('/users/{user}/edit', [UserController::class, 'edit']);
Route::put('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'destroy'])->name('users.destroy');

Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'store']);
?>
```

I attempted to authenticate the user using the credentials provided in the login form. I expected Laravel to correctly authenticate the user if the credentials were correct. I also set validation rules in the `store()` method of the `LoginController` using `$request->validate([...])`. I expected that if the email and password fields were not filled correctly, Laravel would display the error messages on the `login.blade.php` view.

When I submit the login form with correct credentials, Laravel doesn't authenticate the user correctly and redirects back to the login page without displaying any error messages. When I submit the form with empty fields or invalid data, the corresponding error messages are also not displayed on the view. Instead, the form is redirected back to the login page without any feedback.

I believe something is missing or configured incorrectly because Laravel is not authenticating the user correctly and not displaying the validation messages.

I would appreciate any help you can provide to solve this issue.

Comment: You must use only English here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and made the necessary corrections. If you could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For feedback from validation you must add fields for this feedback: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#validation-errors

Answer (score 0):

You are initially  validating email and password which is good. After failed login you are throwing an exception, that's why it will not redirect you to login page. That's why should redirect to previous page with errors.

so modify your store method like below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $request->session()->put('user', $user);
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'Invalid email or password used.']);

}
```

now inside your blade file of login page use below code , this will print error . Modify design or something according to need

```
@if($errors->any())
   <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```

Comment: When the user is not found a message appears, until then it is correct! However, if I add a user who is registered in the bank, it is as if he has not yet been found and the error message appears in the same way.

Comment: With some tests I found that the registrations made through seeds work and the login is carried out, but those that are registered by hand do not work.